# SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, websphere-liberty

I've been going in circles on this one. We're using WebSphere Liberty, Eclipse, and Maven. I'm getting several warnings like

`[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path xercesImpl.jar can not be found in jar file file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xalan-2.7.1.jar or its parent.`

when I start up the server. For all the "class path something.jar"s, they are there in the Maven Dependencies folder in my project, and in my repo though they have a version number attached (e.g. xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar). It claims that the application is available, but if I try to go to the address, I get all kinds of nasty errors, mostly class not found.

When I try to package my project through Maven, I'm getting

`[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to all-external-repositories-mirror (http://mirror/m2-repo/content/groups/adc-standard-repositories): null to http://mirror/m2-repo/content/groups/adc-standard-repositories/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml`

I'm about 70% sure this problem comes down to the fact that our project's Maven uses a mirror that I can't access from here, and I'm about 90% sure there is a work around to use my local repo, but I haven't been able to figure out where to look to make that change. I tried searching the entire workspace for any mention of xerces or xalan, but came up with nothing.

I swear it was using my local repo before as long as I had the jars. I also find it strange that it compiles and lets me run tests without complaining about this.

Any ideas, even just on where to look would be greatly appreciated. A good number of the things I found talking about a similar error mention WebSphere (and more specifically Liberty) so I'm also wondering if it has something to do with the way WebSphere deploys.

Answer (score 4):

It has actually nothing with WebSphere. In your `xalan-2.7.1.jar` which is added to the project, there is `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. And in it, you will find classpath like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.3.1 
Main-Class: org.apache.xalan.xslt.Process
Class-Path: xercesImpl.jar xml-apis.jar serializer.jar
```

as you can see classpath refers to `xercesImpl.jar`, unfortunately your build is creating `xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar`, so it just cannot be resolved. However this is only a warning and application should run fine if the xercesImpl classes are available in the classpath.

Comment: I did find that. Maybe this isn't my problem then? When I was searching for the errors I was getting when going to the webapp, I found something about this being an underlying issue.